# AWS Lightsail Windows SQL Server Unable to connect via static IP

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-lightsail

I created a new windows server + sql server in aws lightsail. I cant seem to connect remotely via ip address. I almost do everything but to no avail.

I tried the ff:

- allow remote connection & windows/sql auth via connection properties
- allow all tcp/udp ports (for testing)
- enable tcp/ip sql config
- add static ip address in tcp/ip sql config
- disable firewall

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What edition and version of SQL Server? Some editions of SQL Server only listen on the localhost address by default, 127.0.0.1, and so cannot be connected to from an external machine. Try opening SQL Server Configuration Manager on the machine and check the TCP/IP configuration in Server Protocols.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning tried that. configured the static public ip on that list. still not working. SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when managing vps, some configurations such as networking are done via the providers interface, in my case its in AWS console. This means that the firewall rule for port 1433 which is used by SQL Server should be configured in the AWS site. There is a networking tab wherein you can add a custom rule to TCP 1433. Also don't forget to set the Server Properties Server Authentication to both windows and sql authentication (Right click the connection > Properties > Security) and then restart sql server service.

Comment: I tried all the things but still unable to connect

Answer (score 0):

There are two version of Lightsail

1. Window + MS SQL
2. Window

When we talk about managing port of MSSQL from Networking tab this will work only when AWS setup MSSQL for you.

if you have just took window and then installed MS SQL from your side you need to do following setting:-

1. Server Server Configuration Manager, enabled TCP/IP from Networking section
   and also open in detail and put port 1433 and remove dynamic ports
2. Create inbound Firewall  in window.

Then it will work.